# Order Pokémons from 1 to 20 not a random order

Tags: javascript, api, for-loop, pokeapi

When I run this code it give me a random order of Pokémons. I don't know where is the problem.

Thank you so much.

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {

    apiPokemon("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+i);

    async function apiPokemon(urlPokemon) {

        const response = await fetch(urlPokemon);
        const dataPokemon = await response.json();

        var id = dataPokemon.id;
        var name = dataPokemon.name;

        console.log(id, name);
    }

}
```

Comment: You may need to `await` the `apiPokemon('...')` call, currently it's firing off all 20 and they can come back in any order.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't put the function inside a loop, instead put the function outside of the loop and call it your loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing's first: "Why are they coming back in random order?" - Because you are not `await`ing each response. Instead you are firing off all 20 async calls which can come back in any order, so that's why they are logging in a random order.

In order to fix this, there are a few changes I'd recommend:

1. Extract your apiPokemon function out of your loop so it doesn't get recreated for each loop iteration
2. Return the entire data object from your apiPokemon function
3. Add all of the apiPokemon requests to an array and await them with `Promise.all()`
4. Log the output of the Promise.all() and you'll see that they will now always be in correct order

```js
async function apiPokemon(urlPokemon) {
  const response = await fetch(urlPokemon);
  const dataPokemon = await response.json();

  return dataPokemon;
}

async function getPokemon(startIndex, stopIndex) {
  let requests = [];
  for (let i = startIndex; i <= stopIndex; i++) {
    requests.push(apiPokemon("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+i)); 
  }
  let pokemonList = await Promise.all(requests);
  for (let pokemon of pokemonList) {
    console.log(pokemon.id, pokemon.name);
  }
}

getPokemon(1, 20)
```

Comment: Ln 9 requests can be const (you are not assigning it to a new reference in memory). Ln 10 var -> should be let.

Comment: @F.Müller I see what you're saying. I copied from the OP, although in both cases it doesn't matter. `const` over `let` is purely preference and I actually prefer to never use `const` unless a variable SHOULD NOT be reassigned, rather than noting if it is not currently reassigned. As for `var` vs `let` here, `var` is actually more memory performant because it doesn't need to create a new variable for each iteration. Since the `i` variable is getting passed as an argument to a function, that value of `i` is persisted in the function call stack

Comment: @F.Müller Nothing about re-assigning `requests` would break the application, for example, if I wanted to say `requests = requests.filter(...)` that is perfectly valid and declaring the original variable as `const` tells me I can't/shouldn't reassign that variable. It makes it ambiguous to the future maintainer of your code whether your code will break or not if a variable is reassigned. Using `const` as a default is very short-sighted in my opinion

Comment: I beg to disagree. `var` is basically deprecated it is only still around for backwards compatibility. But `let` and `const` got introduced because `var` let to bugs because of scope. There is not really a good reason to use it anymore. I know you copied the code, still I'd change it. Regarding `const requests` -> why would you want to reassign it like ever? That's a code smell. Reassigning may lead to bugs and it makes no sense to reassign to the same name after you filter it -> I'd call it filteredRequests or something akin in this case. But in this context, anyway. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: "`var` is basically deprecated it is only still around for backwards compatibility" That's usually how I treat it, but that statement is inaccurate. `var` gives you a function-scoped variable whose declaration is hoisted, whereas `let` gives you a block-scoped variable. They do totally different things. As to the question of "why would you want to reassign it like ever?" that's exactly why I said using `const` as a default is very short-sighted. You don't know how the code will evolve. Defaulting to `const` puts unnecessary restraints on the code and removes the meaning of the keyword

Comment: They are not that different it's just the scope and I hope I don't have to tell you that global variables are pretty bad in general. Every linter will yell at you, if you dare using var. It's just bad. In this particular example snippet there is no reason to do that either. While the evolving part is true, I disagree on the `const` part. It communicates that you should not mess around with that variable it is a final reference in memory and the value of the pointer is still mutable. The code should fit the current needs you should not assume that you want to reassign stuff later.

Comment: https://medium.com/dailyjs/use-const-and-make-your-javascript-code-better-aac4f3786ca1

Comment: @F.Müller [I can post links to articles that support my point, too](https://medium.com/@PepsRyuu/use-let-by-default-not-const-58773e53db52) The point is, there are pros and cons to both approaches. There is no objectively best way to declare variables with `let` vs `const`, hence why my original comment said "[it's] purely preference..."